# SQL Builder for PHP, with JOIN support?

Tags: php, sql, join, builder, sqlbuilder

Are any of you aware of a library that helps you build/manipulate SQL queries, that supports JOIN's?

It would give a lot of flexibility i'd think if you have something where you could return an object, that has some query set, and still be able to apply JOIN's to it, subqueries and such.

I've search around, and have only found SQL Builder, which seems very basic, and doesn't support joins. Which would be a major feature that would really make it useful.

Comment: How much functionality are you looking for?  An OO abstraction of SQL? An ORM?  A 'smart' query builder that you can hand a list of fields & a list of conditions and let 'magically' build a query for you?

Answer (score 7):

Maybe you can try an [ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping), like [Propel](http://propel.phpdb.org/trac/) or [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/), they have a nice programmatic query language, and they return you arrays of objects that represent rows in your database...

For example with Doctrine you can do joins like this:

```
$q = Doctrine_Query::create();
$q->from('User u')
->leftJoin('u.Group g')
->innerJoin('u.Phonenumber p WITH u.id > 3')
->leftJoin('u.Email e');

$users = $q->execute();
```

And with Propel:

```
$c = new Criteria(AuthorPeer::DATABASE_NAME);

$c->addJoin(AuthorPeer::ID, BookPeer::AUTHOR_ID, Criteria::INNER_JOIN);
$c->addJoin(BookPeer::PUBLISHER_ID, PublisherPeer::ID, Criteria::INNER_JOIN);
$c->add(PublisherPeer::NAME, 'Some Name');

$authors = AuthorPeer::doSelect($c);
```

and you can do a lot more with both...

Comment: well. many people like it. But using proprietary sql -like language to replace sql never seemed right to me.

Comment: @Stann I agree with you, considering SQL is more complex than what the propietary sql like languages do

Answer (score 4):

[Zend_Db_Select](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.select.html) from the [Zend_Db](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.html) package of the [Zend Framework](http://framework.zend.com/) can do such things as:

```
// Build this query:
//   SELECT p."product_id", p."product_name", l.*
//   FROM "products" AS p JOIN "line_items" AS l
//     ON p.product_id = l.product_id
$select = $db->select()
    ->from(array('p' => 'products'), array('product_id', 'product_name'))
    ->join(array('l' => 'line_items'), 'p.product_id = l.product_id');
```

(from [Example 11.54. Example of the join() method](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.select.html#zend.db.select.building.join) in the Zend Framework Manual)

If you don't like to run a full-blown ORM package, this could be the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend CakePHP. It creates joins for you automatically, based on the associations between tables.

Say if you were writing a blog:

```
app/model/post.php:

class Post extends AppModel {
  var $hasMany = array('Comment');
}

app/controller/posts_controller.php:

function view($id) {
  $this->set('post', $this->Post->read(null, $id));
}

app/views/posts/view.ctp:

<h2><?php echo $post['Post']['title']?></h2>
<p><?php echo $post['Post']['body']; /* Might want Textile/Markdown here */ ?></p>
<h3>Comments</h3>
<?php foreach($post['Comment'] as $comment) { ?>
  <p><?php echo $comment['body']?></p>
  <p class="poster"><?php echo $comment['name']?></p>
<?php } ?>
```

That would be all you have to write to view a blog post, your database schema is read and cached. As long as you keep it consistent with the conventions, you don't have to tell cake anything about how your table is set up.

```
posts:
id INT
body TEXT
created DATETIME

comments:
id INT
body TEXT
name VARCHAR
post_id INT
```

It has adapters to support MySQL, MSSQL, PostgreSQL, SQLite, Oracle and others. You can also wrap webservices as models, and even get it to do joins between data in your database and remote data! It's very clever stuff.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

superfast SQLObject based IteratorQuery from pastaPHP
 
iterates over resource

```
 foreach(_from('users u')
   ->columns("up.email_address AS EmailAddress", "u.user_name AS u.UserName")
   ->left('userprofiles up', _eq('u.id', _var('up.id')))
   ->where(_and()->add(_eq('u.is_active',1)))
   ->limit(0,10)
   ->order("UserName")
   ->execute("myConnection") as $user){

   echo sprintf(
          '<a href="mailto:%s">%s</a><br/>', 
          $user->EmailAdress, 
          $user->UserName
   );
 }
```

Comment: Do you have a reference link from where you can see this library?

Answer (score 1):

FluentPDO looks nice if you're already using PDO: https://github.com/envms/fluentpdo

Answer (score 0):

I would advise using a PHP framework such as Symfony which uses Propel by default and can use Doctrine if you wish.

CakePHP also uses an ORM, but I don't know which one.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a SQL builder with complex join support: http://laravel.com/docs/queries

Answer (score 0):

I use the query builder from the *phptoolcase library*, it uses pdo connector, has join support.

http://phptoolcase.com/guides/ptc-qb-guide.html

You can use it with the connection manager fro the library to setup multiple database connection very quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Try magsql https://github.com/maghead/magsql, a SQL builder designed for performance written in PHP, comes with join support and cross-platform SQL generation.

It's currently used in the fastest pure PHP orm "maghead"

Answer (score -1):

You can use lenkorm it's very easy:

select('contents)->left('categories ON categories.category.id = contents.category_id)->where('content_id = 1')->result();

or you can use as:

select('contents)->left('categories->using(categoru_id)->where('content_id = 1')->result();

[Download it from github](https://github.com/guncebektas/lenkorm)